# inno setup doesn't decompress each .bin file

Tags: inno-setup

I downloaded an iso which contains the files

```
setup.exe
setup-1.bin
setup-2.bin
```

It fails to install by executing the setup.exe so I analyzed it with innoextract, which opens just setup-1.bin but not setup-2.bin. Can I manually decompress the .bin files or modify the setup.exe? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: This looks really strange why should the Inno do That? I think there is no way how to uncompress only one bin file. Anyway you can extract all files (from .exe and both .bin(s) by running innounp (Inno Setup command line unpacker utility).

Comment: Yeah I tried that for like 5 hours yesterday.. I think the second bin file is just corrupted, so i'm unable to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the second bin file is just corrupted, so i'm unable to extract it.

That is the reason why Inno Setup cannot continue in installation.

I think this is an answer - you simply need to download the installer again.